# How does one calculate the electric field exerted by a point charge on a ring

Tags: electrostatics

It is well known that the electric field by a ring on a point charge can be easily calculated by integrating the each infinitesimal electric field by each infinitesimal charge.
However if one were to attempt to calculate the contrary, that is, electric field exerted by a point charge on a ring, how can one integrate each infinitesimal electric field by the point charge on the ring, since unlike the former, the electric field in the latter case is not generated by an infinitesimal charge, rather by a well defined, let's consider, Q charge?

Comment: Do you know the method of a mirror charge?  this applies since all E lines are perpendichuar to the ring.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the electric *field* of a point charge evaluated *at* the location of the ring? Then you don't do what you're saying: that is, there is an electric field vector that the point charge makes at each point on the ring, and you can just evaluate these electric field vectors separately using Coulomb's Law. However, if you are looking for the total *force* that a point charge exerts on a uniformly *charged* ring, then just use Newton's 3rd Law: you've computed the force the ring exerts on the point charge. Just flip it around, and that's the net force on the ring.

Comment: The integration is over the charge *feeling* the force so you still integrate over the infinitesimal charges making up the ring.